# include CSS settings in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code changes the background every second or the time that is given , but the image does not come with the css properties ( center , cover , position ) , how do I include this function the CSS settings for the images of the background?

```
$(function() {
  var body = $('body');
  var backgrounds = ['url(http://static.jsbin.com/images/jsbin_static.png)', 'url(http://static.jsbin.com/images/popout.png)'];
var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
  body.css(
   'background',
    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
 );
 setTimeout(nextBackground, 1000);
 }
 setTimeout(nextBackground, 1000);
   body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
 });
```

Comment: download images beacuse maybe  in 1sec  your internet  can not upload image online.. Your  code is working here https://jsbin.com/murizorotu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Phoenix 
I put 1 second only to demonstrate that the code works , the question is how to set style settings do not quite understand what you mean rs

Answer (score 1):

element have a style.backgroundImage property to manipulate the background image. To set the background image in javascript:

```
body.style.backgroundImage = "url('yoururl')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `background` can take *shorthand* values for all of it's properties so you can do:

```
background: url(image);
background: url(image) center;
background: url(image) center no-repeat;
background: #000 url(image) center no-repeat;
etc.
```

So you can do it with jQuery the same way:

```
$(element)
   .css('background','url(image)')
   .css('background','url(image) center')
   .css('background','url(image) center no-repeat')
   .css('background','#000 url(image) center no-repeat')
   etc
```

Comment: I tried to apply the code to mine, but it did not work , you can apply your example in jsFiddle so I can understand it , please?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in pure CSS:

```css
@keyframes backgrounds {
  0% {
    background-image: url(http://static.jsbin.com/images/jsbin_static.png);
  }
  
  50% {
    background-image: url(http://static.jsbin.com/images/popout.png);
  }
}

.rotating-background {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: backgrounds 2s steps(1, end) infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating-background"></div>
```